# php array how get in array value for using foreach

Tags: php

I have multiple array, I want particular value get using `foreach` below my code

> Notice: Undefined index: transId in  on line 52

```
$test = array(
    'messages' => Array
    (
        'resultCode' => 'Ok',
        'message' => Array
        (
            'code' => 'I00001',
            'text' => 'Successful',
        ),

    ),
    'transactionResponse' => Array
    (
        'responseCode' => '1',
        'authCode' => 'Z7K31J',
        'avsResultCode' => 'Y',
        'cvvResultCode' => 'P',
        'cavvResultCode' => '2',
        'transId' => '40004672975',
        'refTransID' => Array
        (
        ),

        'transHash' => '163382584395AB06470CF365AD6F7381',
        'testRequest' => '0',
        'accountNumber' => 'XXXX4242',
        'accountType' => 'Visa',
        'messages' => Array
        (
            'message' => Array
                (
                    'code' => '1',
                    'description' => 'This transaction has been approved',
                ),

        ),
        'transHashSha2' => Array
        (
        ),
    ),
);
```

above my array, execute `$test` in foreach

I want display value of `transid`, `response`, `transhash`

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {  
    $response = $value['resultCode'];
    $transId = $value['transId'];
    $authCode = $value['authCode'];
    $transHash = $value['transHash'];
}
```

Comment: `$value['transactionResponse']['transId']`

Comment: @Janak vyas do want it form only second array  'transactionResponse' ?

Comment: You cant use foreach for what you want. You dont have transId, authCode or transHash in messages array, and also resultCode in transactionResponse array.

Comment: i get  Undefined index: transactionResponse

Comment: i want also resultcode

Comment: do want it from second array ?

Comment: @JagdishChaudhary yes i want both array value like resultCode, transId,authCode,transHash

Comment: ok is your array is fixed now or it will be change ?

Comment: it will be change

Comment: ok i will give you answer hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `array_walk_recursive()` where you don't have to go in each level of the array to echo your values like below:

```
<?php
  array_walk_recursive($test, function ($item, $key){
    if($key == 'transId' || $key == 'transHash' || $key == 'resultCode'){
        echo $key." => ".$item."<br>";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need foreach:

```
$response = $test['messages']['resultCode'];
$transId = $test['transactionResponse']['transId'];
$authCode = $test['transactionResponse']['authCode'];
$transHash = $test['transactionResponse']['transHash'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value)
{
   if(!empty($value['message']))
   {
      $response = $value['messages']['resultCode'];
   }
   elseif(!empty($value['transactionResponse']))
   {
        $transId = $value['transactionResponse']['transId'];
        $authCode = $value['transactionResponse']['authCode'];
        $transHash = $value['transactionResponse']['transHash'];
   }
}
```

if you want proper then you have to take it to array and key as your transid